# É possível armazenar um ArrayList em um Banco de Dados em Java?

Tags: java, mysql, banco-de-dados, arraylist

Tratando-se de `Banco de Dados` utilizando `Java`, é possível armazenar um objeto `ArrayList` em um `Banco de Dados` `MySql`? Se sim, como posso armazenar este tipo de dado? E como posso recuperá-lo da base de Dados? Se possível, poderiam mostrar um exemplo simples?

Comment: Você quer armazenar os dados que contem no ArrayList?

Comment: Eu quero armazenar um objeto ArrayList como um todo dentro do banco. Exemplo, tenho `ArrayList` `myArray` = `[2,43,1,4,11,78,43]`. Gostaria de poder armazenar o objeto `myArray`. E posteriormente, pode realizar um `select` e resgatar o objeto `myArray` por completo (`[2,43,1,4,11,78,43]`). O armazenamento do `myArray` deverá ficar em uma única tupla, não em 7 tuplas

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A pergunta está feita de forma inapropriada. Dá para entender que você tem uma lista de valores e quer salvar isso num banco MySQL, mas esses são dois mundos completamente diferentes e você precisa entender como eles se relacionam.

A resposta correta depende de vários fatores.

## Modelo de dados

O banco de dados não sabe nada de Java e nem precisa saber. Então, primeiramente, você deve definir um modelo de dados capaz de armazenar os valores.

O modelo mais "correto" seria armazenar os valores cada um em um registro, talvez numa tabela com um relacionamento `1:N` (um para muitos) com uma tabela principal, no caso da lista estar vinculada a outro registro.

Pelo seu comentário, você quer armazenar os valores em um único campo. Enquanto isso é geralmente mais "confortável" do ponto de vista do programador, pode gerar diversos efeitos colaterais. O caso mais simples é caso você precisa pesquisar registros procurando por valores dessa lista, pois nesse caso você não pode simplesmente usar uma cláusula `WHERE`, mas precisará percorrer todos os registros.

Se isso não for um problema, provavelmente seu modelo vai conter um campo `VARCHAR` para armazenar a lista em formato texto. Nesse caso, a pergunta poderia ser simplesmente sobre como converter uma lista para texto e depois de novo para uma lista.

## Armazenando uma lista num campo texto

Caso a ideia seja apenas armazenar números inteiros e você esteja usando Java 8, dá pra converter uma lista para uma String facilmente, assim:

```
List<Integer> lista = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3);
String texto = lista.stream()
        .map(String::valueOf)
        .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
```

O código basicamente pega a lista de inteiros, converte para uma lista de strings e junta tudo separando por vírgula.

Depois, para pegar o texto e reconstruir a lista, pode fazer assim:

```
List<Integer> novaLista = Arrays.stream(texto.split(","))
        .map(Integer::valueOf)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

O código quebra o texto separando por vírgulas, converte cada item para um `Integer` e finalmente recupera o resultado numa lista.

Você precisa tomar cuidado com o tamanho do campo, para não exceder o número de caracteres.

Além disso, esta abordagem não é segura para outros tipos de dados que podem conter vírgulas nos valores.

## Armazenando a lista usando serialização

Outra abordagem seria serializar o `ArrayList` usando a API de serialização do Java, armazenando o objeto como uma sequência de bytes, que poderia ser desserializada posteriormente.

É apenas uma ideia e existem outras respostas aqui no SO ensinando como fazer isso.

Esta abordagem é flexível pois permite armazenar qualquer tipo de lista, desde que os objetos dentro dela sejam também serializáveis.

O problema é que uma sequência de bytes no banco de dados não é algo muito agradável de lidar.

## Armazenando a lista usando JSON

Outra alternativa mais flexível é converter o `ArrayList` em um objeto JSON e armazenar isso no banco de dados. JSON é um formato de representação de objeto em texto, por exemplo:

```
{ itens = [ 1, 2, 3 ] }
```

Esta abordagem é a mais flexível porque permite que qualquer tipo de dado seja armazenado.

A desvantagem é você ter que usar uma API mais complexa para converter ente `ArrayList` e JSON. Existem várias respostas aqui no SO que ensinam como gerar JSON ou vice-versa.

Answer (score 0):

Caso você esteja trabalhando com o `JPA`, acredito que a própria [documentação da Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/CollectionTable.html) aborde o assunto de forma bastante clara.

No link acima, é exemplificado de forma bastante simplória como irá ser manipulado a anotação que faz o "trabalho pesado".